# Can I add new data when I retrieve my data as an angularfire $firebaseObject to my database or only change/remove data?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am learning Angularfire and I have lot of questions, but one that is really bugging me is the following. I have read on a lot of different sites (including Firebase.com) on how to retrieve data from a firebase and they make all make a difference between giving back your data back as an array ($firebaseArray) or object($firebaseObject). Objects are great for three-way binding but what if I want to add new stuff to my database?

A `$firebaseArray` has a `$add` method, but a `$firebaseObject` doesn't. So what is the deal here and when to use `$firebaseArray` vs. `$firebaseObject`. Or is there a method to add new data with a `$firebaseObject` and am I just not seeing it?

Can somebody give me a bit of clearity. I am using angularfire 1.0.0. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is an entire guide written with the purpose of teaching fundamentals. It's quite a good read and will save you a great deal of energy figuring out concepts like basic read/write: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/

Comment: @Kato Yes, thanks for the link I saw that too. I was looking at this docs: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html and although they are good they certainly not spoon feed you :). Are you a member of the AngularFire team? I really like Firebase and the AngularFire API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to modify existing objects, use `$firebaseObject`, use `$firebaseArray` to add new objects to the array of objects,

**Example:** To get all orders form a customer and then to get a particular order

```
AM.value("DB_URL","https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/");    
AM.factory("DB", ["DB_URL",    
  function(DB_URL) {  
    var db = new Firebase(DB_URL);    
    return db;
  }  
]);  
AM.factory("Orders", ["$firebaseArray", "DB","Auth","$firebaseObject","$log",  
  function($firebaseArray,DB,Auth,$firebaseObject,$log) {  
    $log.debug("Fetching Orders");  
    var authData = Auth.$getAuth();  
    var ordersRef = DB.child("users/" + authData.uid+"/orders/");  
    $log.debug("ordersRef = " + ordersRef);  
    var Orders = $firebaseArray(ordersRef);

  return {  
    getOrders: function() {  
      return Orders;  
    },  

    getOrder: function(orderId) {  
       $log.debug("Order for id: " + orderId);  
       var orderRef = ordersRef.child(orderId);  
       $log.debug("orderRef = " + orderRef);  
       var Order = $firebaseObject(orderRef); 
       return Order;  
    }  
  };
 }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, so it is not one or the other as I understand. You can use them both depending where the user finds it self on the page. Interestingly this explains more than the docs it self. I find myself struggling with the docs especially...authorization. You have any good source to learn from?

Comment: Best source to learn from is firebase itself. e.g. See authorization example codes at https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-users-and-authentication.